# Как сбросить float с помощью css3?

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

На данный момент я просто пишу пустой блок `<div style="clear:both"></div>`. Но может быть можно без лишних блоков? :after какой-нибудь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/css-tricks/clearfix.html

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно имитировать такой же блок, как вы написали, то можно делать так:

```
.clear:after{
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Но лучше в нужного блока прописывать `overflow:hidden` и делать высоту автоматической — результат, в большинстве случаев, будет такой же.